# How to make a deep-filter in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, nested, predicate

I have this scheme procedure that makes a list of all the things in a (nested) list for which the predicate is true.

```
(define (deep-filter f lst)
 (cond
  ((null? lst) '())
  ((and (atom? lst) (f lst)) lst)
  ((atom? lst) '() )
  (else (cons (deep-filter f (car lst)) 
              (deep-filter f (cdr lst))))))
```

An example:

```
 (deep-filter number? '(2 (a ((c)) (1)) 6)) => (2 (() ((())) (1)) 6)
```

Is it possible to fix this procedure so that it doesn't print empty lists?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(define (deep-filter f lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((and (atom? lst) (f lst)) (list lst))
    ((atom? lst) '())
    (else (append (deep-filter f (car lst)) 
                  (deep-filter f (cdr lst))))))
```

It's called *flattening* a list, the trick is using `append` instead of `cons` and packing single elements (second case in the `cond`) inside a list. Notice that this will eliminate all sublists, returning only the elements that satisfy the predicate.

If you need to preserve list structure after removing empty lists, then do this instead:

```
(define (deep-filter f lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((atom? (car lst))
         (if (f (car lst))
             (cons (car lst) (deep-filter f (cdr lst)))
             (deep-filter f (cdr lst))))
        (else
         (filter (compose not null?)
                 (cons (deep-filter f (car lst)) 
                       (deep-filter f (cdr lst)))))))
```

Now it will work as expected:

```
(deep-filter number? '(2 (a ((c)) (b)) 6))
=> '(2 6)

(deep-filter number? '(2 (a ((c)) (1)) 6))
=>'(2 ((1)) 6)

(deep-filter number? '(2 (a ((4)) (1)) 6))
=> '(2 (((4)) (1)) 6)

(deep-filter number? '(2 (a ((4)) (1)) 6 ((((((b))))))))
=> '(2 (((4)) (1)) 6)
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but unfortunately I need the things (numbers in the example) to stay in the original position (they have to stay in a nested list if they were in one). The things for which the predicate is false have to be removed, as well as the lists where they were in...

Comment: @Neyuh I see. For the example in the question, what would be the expected output?

Comment: '(2 (a ((c)) (1)) 6)) => (2 ((1)) 6))

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have to delete the filter line in the else.
I have this:
(define (deep-filter f lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((atom? (car lst))
         (if (f (car lst))
             (cons (car lst) (deep-filter f (cdr lst)))
             (deep-filter f (cdr lst))))
        (else
                 (cons (deep-filter f (car lst)) 
                       (deep-filter f (cdr lst))))))

Comment: What do you mean _delete_? you can't use `filter` in your solution??

Comment: Edit: It doesn't work; Try this:

(deep-filter2 number? '(2 (a ((4)) (1)) 6 ((((((b))))))))

Comment: @Neyuh I edited the answer a couple of times, try with the most recent version above - it works even with that last example, returning `'(2 (((4)) (1)) 6)`. Notice that the list with the `b` will be removed completely, because it contains no numbers

Comment: @Neyuh and by the way, you shouldn't _delete_ the `filter` procedure. If necessary implement it yourself as a helper procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think this isn't the right solution. It's too complicated to be possible. It's only my 1st year in university...
I'll use your first solution.

Comment: @Neyuh the problem as stated is not _that_ simple, so it needed a solution a bit more complicated. Anyway you could've implemented your own `filter` and use it as a helper procedure, that's well within the scope of a 1st year course. Also, please don't forget to accept this answer if it was helpful for you.